# How do you let scrapy yield all items?

Tags: python, scrapy

I just learned scrapy recently.
How do you let scrapy yield all items?

For example, if I want to extract a `book`.
And the home page is the `book title`, layer two is the `chapter`, layer three is the `article`.

```
class BookSpider(scrapy.spider.Spider):
   name = 'book'
   allowed_domains = ['book.com']
   start_urls = ['http://www.book.com']

   def __init__(self):
      self.items = []

   def parse(self, response):
      link = response.xpath('//chapter').extract()

      for l in links:
         yield Request(l, callback=self.parse_chapter)

      print self.items

   def parse_chapter(self, response):
      link = response.xpath('//article').extract()

      for l in links:
         yield Request(l, callback=self.parse_article)
      return

   def parse_article(self, response):
      item = BookItem()
      item['article'] = response.url
      self.items.append(item)
      return
```

But the result is just an empty list. Why is `self.items` not able to be built?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return or yield item or a list of items from any of the callbacks:

```
def parse_article(self, response):
    item = BookItem()
    item['article'] = response.url
    return item
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. But what I want is an item list, not single items. Is that possible?

Comment: @Jay since `parse_article` would be called multiple times along the way, you'll have multiple items in the output anyway.

Comment: Hi, alecxe, I know that, and that is how I work right now. But I really want an entire list for output.

Comment: @Jay just a list of article urls?

Comment: hi, alecxe, sorry I just give an example. Actually, every single item has 13 keys.

Comment: @Jay thanks, still not sure why you need a list, pipe the spider output to JSON and you'll see a list of dicts (items).